# TypeError: 'Piece' object is not subscriptable in Class type in Python

Tags: python

The Below code is used to name the possible xy-coordinates of chess pieces.

For instance: (1,1) for rook means the rook can move n*1 in x direction or n*1 in y-direction.

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self,pawn1, rook2, knight3, bishop4, queen5, king6):
        self.rook2 = rook2
        self.pawn1 = pawn1
        self.knight3 =knight3
        self.bishop4 = bishop4
        self.king6 = king6
        self.queen5 = queen5

a = Piece((1,2),(0,1),(3,1),(1,1),(0,1,1),(0,1))

def rook_move(n):
    rook_move1 = n*rnd.random(a[2])
    return rook_move1
rook_move(3)
```

I get this error:

```
rook_move1 = n*rnd.random(a[2])
TypeError: 'Piece' object is not subscriptable
```

Can you please tell me what is the problem?

I tried both Lists and tuples. Trying to build a very basic, non-intuitive chess game.

Comment: what do you try to get with `a[2]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, this error

`TypeError: 'X' object is not subscriptable`

is there to tell you that x[i] (when x is an X object) does not exist, because x is not a list of any sort.

in your case, you probably want to be specific about which attribute of a you want, any of which are tuples!

for examle:

```
def rook_move(n):
    rook_move1 = n*rnd.random(a.rook2[2])
    return rook_move1
rook_move(3)
```

you see, `a` is not list-like, thus there is no such a thing as `a[2]`

but `a.rook2` IS list-like indeed, (in that case we only have `a.rook2[0]` or `a.rook2[1]` but you get the point)

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a Piece object, not a list. so you can't use code like: a[2]